# Detect browser type and version in jQuery to work with responsive design

Tags: jquery, css

what i wanna do is to create three different design templates according to the browser version and size i do not want to use all the responsive design principles so if the user decrease the size of the browser it will modify and apply the new design .

any resource's and links will be great ,the problem that i found a lot of examples but not a tutorial for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is how to detect  browser an ...:
http://www.tvidesign.co.uk/blog/CSS-Browser-detection-using-jQuery-instead-of-hacks.aspx
http://www.ilovecolors.com.ar/detect-screen-size-css-style/
and for the second issue :
http://www.greengoatmedia.com/blog/10-new-responsive-design-web-design-examples.html
http://getskeleton.com/
http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2011/09/the-ultimate-responsive-web-design-roundup/
http://designmodo.com/responsive-design-examples/

Enjoy :)

Comment: i found a link is linked it one of the posted links by you and it just do the job thanks

Answer (score 1):

try following code,

```
var browser = '';
var browserVersion = 0;

if (/Opera[\/\s](\d+\.\d+)/.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
    browser = 'Opera';
} else if (/MSIE (\d+\.\d+);/.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
    browser = 'MSIE';
} else if (/Navigator[\/\s](\d+\.\d+)/.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
    browser = 'Netscape';
} else if (/Chrome[\/\s](\d+\.\d+)/.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
    browser = 'Chrome';
} else if (/Safari[\/\s](\d+\.\d+)/.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
    browser = 'Safari';
    /Version[\/\s](\d+\.\d+)/.test(navigator.userAgent);
    browserVersion = new Number(RegExp.$1);
} else if (/Firefox[\/\s](\d+\.\d+)/.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
    browser = 'Firefox';
}
if(browserVersion === 0){
    browserVersion = parseFloat(new Number(RegExp.$1));
}
alert(browser + "*" + browserVersion);
```

Comment: it is not just the browser issue is my problem it is how to apply the responsive design up on my application but thanks that's help too :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [headJS](http://www.headjs.com) for this. It can also load Javascript and has many more functions. But in your `<html>` tag will get something like:

```
class="mozilla w-1500 lt-1680 lt-1920 root-section js  gradient rgba opacity textshadow multiplebgs boxshadow borderimage borderradius no-cssreflections csstransforms csstransitions no-fontface domloaded"
```

Where the width browser and css options are shown. The width is automaticly updated so you can easily create your CSS without using any other Javascript

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
$(document) .ready( function() {
    alert("broser name:"+navigator.appName);
    alert("broser version:"+navigator.appVersion);
});
```